# Двухколоночные списки в Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Как сделать следующий список

> 1 6
>   2 7
>   3 8
>   4 9
>   5 10

Чтобы на мобильных устройствах он выравнивался по-порядку

> 1
>   2
>   3
>   4
>   ...

Забыл добавить, нужно еще чтобы 1-6, 2-7, 3-8, ... чтобы каждая из этих пар была на одной линии, то есть высота 1 = высоте 6, высота 2 = высоте 7 и т.д. Количество контента в каждой ячейке разное.

Answer (score 1):

Если правильно понял, пример снизу.

***Пример***:

```css
div.column {
  border: 3px solid black;
}

div.column-1 {
  background: yellow;
}

div.column-2 {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="column column-1">
        <p>
          1
          <br> 2
          <br> 3
          <br> 4
          <br> 5
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="column column-2">
        6
        <br> 7
        <br> 8
        <br> 9
        <br> 10
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Можно к бутстраповским колонкам добавить к блокам текста псевдоэлемент :before со счётчиком, а потом настроить внешний вид номера и его положение относительно текста:

   - [`:before`](https://webref.ru/css/before)
   - [`content`](https://webref.ru/css/content)
   - [`counter-reset`](https://webref.ru/css/counter-reset)
   - [`ounter-increment`](https://webref.ru/css/counter-increment)

   .
   Вот решение аналогичной задачи. В нём номера нанизаны на вертикальную линию, но её можно убрать.

   [so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38421672/6263942)  •  [codepen](https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/vKdKpR)

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

body {
  background: lightgrey; 
}

.timeline {
  background: white; 
  counter-reset: section;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding-left: 70px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.timeline .col-xs-12 {
  border-left: solid 4px orange;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 60px;
}

.timeline .col-xs-12:before {
  /* counter */
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counter(section);
  /* position */
  position: absolute;
  left: -22px; /* = (width + border-left) / 2 */
  top: -30px;
  /* form & size */
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  /* colors & text */
  background: orange;
  color: white;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

/* images */
.timeline img {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .col-xs-6 {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container timeline">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12 col-md-6"><img src="//placehold.it/900x300/c69/f9c/?text=First" alt=""></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12 col-md-6"><img src="//placehold.it/900x300/9c6/cf9/?text=Second" alt=""></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.
          A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.
          A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.
          A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.
          A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.
          A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.
          A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.
          A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.
          A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.
          A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.
          A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12 col-md-6"><img src="//placehold.it/900x300/69c/9cf/?text=Three" alt=""></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12 col-md-6"><img src="//placehold.it/900x300/96c/c9f/?text=Four" alt=""></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.
          A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.
          A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.
          A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.
          A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

2. Чтобы выравнивать первый номер с шестым и т.д., можно написать скрипт, который при изменении ширины экрана будет менять макет из двух-колоночного в пяти-рядный и обратно. Но имхо это неоправданные затраты:

   - хлопот много,
   - появятся дыры между блоками по вертикали,
   - из-за этих дыр посетители будут путаться как читать блоки — слева направо или сверху вниз.